# C# selenium webdriver raise InvalidOperationException ocurred in WebDriver.dll

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am trying to use the selenium driver for automation test.

I have installed this NuGet Packages:

[image]

My simple code and the error:

[image]

It is my project structure with the references:

[image]

I don't know what or where the problem is?

#### More info

- VS Professional 2013, Version 12.0.40629.00 Update 5
- .NET Framework Version 4.6.01.0.55
- Selenium.WebDriver 2.53.0
- WebDriverChromeDriver 2.10
- Google Chrome Version 51.0.2704.84 m

#### View Detail...

There is the View Detail... from the error System.InvalidOperationException:

[image]

And the Stack Trace message:

```
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeOptions options)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor()
   at SeleniumFirst.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\roberto.cardenas\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SeleniumFirst\SeleniumFirst\Program.cs:line 17
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Did you add the ChromeDriver.exe reference?

Comment: Do I need to add as a reference? Or I think the program looking for `chromedriver.exe` in the same directory that the program is running?? Am I wrong?

Comment: I am not able to recall, but I think it will look for the exe in the path environment variable or the one user has suggested. But if you click on viewdetails and then get the exception call stack, that should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem was with the chromedriver.exe file. I installed the version 2.10 using the NuGet Packages Manager but I was reading this [post](http://powerdotnetcore.com/selenium/tip-2-basic-installation-of-selenium-webdriver-in-visual-studio-c-sharp) and I did the steps. But in case to avoid an answer with a broken link for the post there is the solution:

So, to resolve this problem you can just navigate to http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and download last stable version:

[image]

In my case was 2.20 so I navigate to: http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.20/

[image]

Later I copied this driver version to C: directory and create a path to the driver:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string DRIVER_PATH = @"C:\";
        //create a reference to our browser
        IWebDriver chrome = new ChromeDriver(DRIVER_PATH);

        //navigate to google page
        chrome.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");

        IWebElement search = chrome.FindElement(By.Name("q"));

        search.SendKeys("executeautomation");
    }
}
```

And everything is ok.

Answer (score 2):

chromedriver.exe needs to be inside the aplication dir and with propriet output as "copy always".

Other way is send a path to chromedriver constructor when you create the object. This allow you put all drivers inside a dir in the current project. As example:

```
var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\Drivers";
var chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(path);

// It will search in "[...]bin\Debug[or Release]\Drivers\chromedriver.exe"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I copied the driver out of the application directory in order to reuse the driver and also because I don't want to have the driver inside of my code. But thank you again for your help.

Comment: Yes, you can do this way for any physical path. My example is if you want to create a folder inside your solution with all drivers thar you want, like chrome, ie, phanton etc

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to update chrome driver. Here is a bug https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1257
The latest version is 2.21

Comment: Thank you @Vitali, the problem was fixed. I was using the version 2.10 and the latest is 2.20.